# Difficulty trying to implement separate UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in my app and I'm trying to pull it's delegate methods into a separate `UITableViewDelegate`. This is what the code looks like:

```
RestaurantViewDelegate *delegate = [[RestaurantViewDelegate alloc] initWithRestaurant:self.restaurant andRecommended:self.recommended];

self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 235.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-235)];
self.tableView.delegate = delegate;
self.tableView.dataSource = delegate;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

And this is what `RestaurantViewDelegate` looks like:

```
// RestaurantViewDelegate.h

@interface RestaurantViewDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *recommendations;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Restaurant *restaurant;

- (id)initWith Restaurant:(Restaurant *)restaurant andRecommended:(NSArray *)recommendations;

@end
```

and

```
// RestaurantViewDelegate.m

@implementation RestaurantViewDelegate

@synthesize recommendations = _recommendations;
@synthesize restaurant = _restaurant;

- (id)initWith Restaurant:(Restaurant *)restaurant andRecommended:(NSArray *)recommendations {

    self = [super init];
    if ( self != nil ) {

        _recommendations = recommendations;
        _restaurant = restaurant;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Recommendations: %d", [_recommendations count]);
    return [_recommendations count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 48.0f;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

@end
```

However, when I run my app and click on a cell, *all* cells disappear. I really don't know what's causing this. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Post more code. What is didSelectRowAtIndexPath doing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting problem. Remember that in ARC (Automatic reference counting ), an object will be retained only as long  as a strong reference to it is maintained. Remember, the 'delegate's are always weak, and in your case it means, once you come out of the scope, where you create the delegate object and setup the table view, there will no longer any delegate object retained. This is the reason you might not see anything happening when you try to reload the table view. Make the delegate object RestaurantViewDelegate a member of your controller. And check..

Comment: Also make sure that you hold a `strong` reference to that delegate in your controller too. Another thing is that your cell is not configured to contain any data. You are just returning an default table view cell. Are you configuring the contents of the cell somewhere?